# Can't use struct pointers as parameters of mutiple functions

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct

This is a program to register books in a library with title, writer and price.As well as calculate things such as averages, highest price book... It ran pretty well when i used a vector {struct livro Livros[1000]} instead of a pointer {struct livro *Livros}.
I used the pointers to dynamically allocate memory for the book list and everything runs fine registering the books. but when i try to calculate the average, which calls another function to main, the program crashes and the compiler(i use visual studio in my school) shows that message:

Unhandled exception at 0x00ec174c in Livraria.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcccccd94.

I tried to use the function to locate by writer instead of the average and it crashed just after i have put the string. Certainly when it used the "Livros[i].autor" to compare the strings

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define flush_toilet (fflush(stdin))
//mude o #define dependendo do seu SO
//__fpurge(stdin); "linux"
//fflush(stdin);    "windows"

struct livro {
char titulo [100];
char autor [100];
float prec;
};

//register
void cadastro (int *qtd, struct livro *Livros){
    int i;
    Livros=NULL;



printf("Insira a quantidade de livros:");//defines the quantity(variable "qtd") of books which will pass to the main function(it worked when i used vectors)
scanf ("%i",qtd);
flush_toilet;

Livros = malloc( *qtd *sizeof(struct livro));    //allocates the memory for the list

printf ("insira os dados de cada livro:");

    for (i=0;i<*qtd;i=i+1){
    printf ("\n\n\ninsira o titulo:"); 
    gets (Livros[i].titulo);      //title
    flush_toilet;

    printf ("\ninsira o nome:");
    gets (Livros[i].autor);      //writer
    flush_toilet;

    printf ("\ninsira o preco :");
    scanf ("%f",&Livros[i].prec);//price
    flush_toilet;
    }
}





//calculate average of prices
float media (int qtd, struct livro *Livros){
int i;
float  media=0;
    for (i=0;i<qtd;i=i+1){
    media=media+Livros[i].prec;
    }

media=media/qtd;
return media;

}


//calculate number of books above average
int qtd_acima_med (float media, struct livro *Livros, int qtd){
int acima=0,i;

    for (i=0;i<qtd;i=i+1){

        if(Livros[i].prec>media){
        acima=acima+1;
        }
    }

return acima;


}


//locate a book by writer
void localizar(int qtd, struct livro *Livros){
int i;
char autor[100];

printf("\ndigite o nome do autor cujos livros deseja encontrar:\n");
gets (autor);
flush_toilet;
printf("\n");

    for (i=0;i<qtd;i=i+1){

        if((strcmp (autor, Livros[i].autor))==0){
        puts(Livros[i].titulo);
        printf("\n");
        }


    }
}


//finds and displays the most expensive book
void mais_caro (int qtd, struct livro *Livros ){
int i, ncaro;
float caro=0;
    for (i=0;i<qtd;i=i+1){

        if (Livros [i].prec>caro){
        caro=Livros [i].prec;
        ncaro=i;
        }

    }

puts (Livros[ncaro].titulo);
printf ("preco:  %f\n", Livros[ncaro].prec);
}


void main (){
struct livro *Livros;

int qtd=-1, selec=1, nacima=-1;
float med=-1;

    while (selec!=0){
    printf ("\n\n\nDigite 0 para sair,\n 1 para cadastrar,\n 2 para calcular a media,\n 3 para calcular os livros acima da media,\n 4 para localizar o livro pelo autor,\n 5 para achar o mais caro.\n\n");
    scanf("%i", &selec);
flush_toilet;
        switch (selec){

            case 0:
            break;


            case 1:{
            cadastro(&qtd, Livros);
            break;
            }


            case 2:{

                if(qtd<0){
                printf("erro nenhum livro cadastrado ou processo de cadastro incorreto\n");
                break;
                }
            med=media(qtd, Livros);
            printf("A media e igual a: %f \n", med);

            break;
            }


            case 3:{

                if(med<0){
                printf("erro a media n foi calculada\n");
                break;
                }

            nacima = qtd_acima_med (med, Livros, qtd);
            printf("A qtd de livros com preco acima da media e: %i \n", nacima);
            break;
            }


            case 4:{
                if(qtd<0){
                printf("erro nenhum livro cadastrado ou processo de cadastro incorreto\n");
                break;
                }

            localizar(qtd, Livros);

            break;
            }


            case 5:{
                if(qtd<0){
                printf("erro nenhum livro cadastrado ou processo de cadastro incorreto\n");
                break;
                }

            mais_caro (qtd, Livros);

            break;
            }
        }

    }

free(Livros);
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is wrong and should be avoided, since this have an undefined behavior. It's meant to be called on stdout.

Comment: `Livros = malloc( *qtd *sizeof(struct livro));` : `Livros` is local variable.

Comment: the function: gets() is depreciated and has so many pitfalls that it should never be use.  Rather use fgets().  Note that fgets() reads in the whole line (unless the char limit parameter is reached),  This includes the newline.  So there is no need for a call to 'fflush(stdin)'  which, per the standard, is undefined behaviour.

Comment: this line: 'void main (){' will cause a compiler to raise a warning because this is not a valid main() declaration.  However, using: 'int main(){' is valid.  Of course, then the code has to return a int at the end, probably by: 'return(0);'

Comment: this line: 'scanf("%i", &selec);'  has a few problems: 1) always check the return code from input statements to assure the operation was successful 2) the format string should contain a leading ' ' (space) so white space (newline, etc) is skipped over. 3) %i is unsigned, while selec is defined as signed (int).  Of particular interest is the following switch() statement does not have a 'default' case, so there is no way to check (and handle) the event of the user not entering a valid value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I compile, I get the following error:

```
1>main.c(138) : warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'Livros' used
```

This looks to be the cause of the bug.  To fix, you need to return the allocated array from `cadastro`:

```
struct livro * cadastro (int *qtd){
    int i;
    struct livro *Livros =NULL;

    printf("Insira a quantidade de livros:");//defines the quantity(variable "qtd") of books which will pass to the main function(it worked when i used vectors)
    scanf ("%i",qtd);
    flush_toilet;

    Livros = malloc( *qtd * sizeof(struct livro));    //allocates the memory for the list

    printf ("insira os dados de cada livro:");

    for (i=0;i<*qtd;i=i+1){
        printf ("\n\n\ninsira o titulo:"); 
        gets (Livros[i].titulo);      //title
        flush_toilet;

        printf ("\ninsira o nome:");
        gets (Livros[i].autor);      //writer
        flush_toilet;

        printf ("\ninsira o preco :");
        scanf ("%f",&Livros[i].prec);//price
        flush_toilet;
    }

    return Livros;
}
```

And then later use the return in `main ()`:

```
void main (){
    struct livro *Livros = NULL;

    int qtd=-1, selec=1, nacima=-1;
    float med=-1;

    while (selec!=0){

// Snip

        switch (selec){

// snip
            case 1:
                {
                    if (Livros != NULL)
                    {
                        free(Livros);
                        Livros = NULL;
                    }
                    Livros = cadastro(&qtd);
                }
                break;
```

You also need to check the return values of `scanf()` and `gets()` in case there is no more input or invalid input, and have a default case in the event the user enters an invalid value for `selec`.  You should also consider replacing [`gets()` with `fgets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used) to prevent buffer overruns.  But the immediate cause of the crash is the uninitialized variable.  Presumably your compiler also reports a similar warning, and if it does, warnings like this should always be fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked as expected. Thanks as well for the hint about gets() and scanf().